# Trying to return a single object from an array of objects angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-ng-repeat

I make a get request which returns an array of objects. I want loop through the array and return one single object to the view based on the name property of that object. I have tried to use `ng-repeat` with a `filter` it just returns the all of the objects.

Is there away which I can filter the data to return 1 object from the array, with out using a search box. I want this to happen as the page is loading up.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="lecturer in lecturers | filter:name: courses.lecturer">
         <h3>{{lecturer.name}}</h3>
         <div>
             <img class="img-circle"  ng-src="{{lecturer.picture}}" alt="" /> 
         </div>
            <p>{{lecturer.description}}</p>  
       </div>
```

**Controller**

```
 $scope.lecturers;
$scope.courses;
$scope.status;

var id = $stateParams.id;

//getCourse() method calls the coursesFac factory/service which calls the api endpoint and returns 

//the course information based on the course id.
$scope.getCourse = function(id){
    coursesFac.getCourseById(id)
        .then(function (response) {
            // var items;
            response.data.video = JSON.parse(response.data.video);
             console.log(response.data.video);
            items = response.data.video;
            $scope.courses = response.data;

           // console.log(items);
            // console.log($scope.courses.video);
        }, function (error) {
            $scope.status = 'Unable to load course data: ' + error.message;
            console.log($scope.status);
        });
};

//passes the state paramater in to the method. The paramater is the course Id 
$scope.getCourse(id);




 $scope.getLecturer = function(){
        lecturerFac.getLecturer()
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.lecturers = response.data;
                console.log("inside the function getLectuers" +$scope.lecturers);
            }, function (error) {
                $scope.status = 'Unable to load lecturer data: ' + error.message;
                console.log($scope.status);
            });
    };
   $scope.getLecturer();
```

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, your function `lecturerFac.getLecturerByName([name])` returns an array of lecturers and you just want one? You should simply be able to just do this:: `$scope.lecturer = reponse.data[0]`. That'll give you the first lecturer returned by your factory function. They're already filtered by name from the server (I'm assuming, based on the name of the function) so you wont be able to filter them further client-side anyways, unless you use a different filter (which it doesn't seem like).

Comment: your filter isn't sane.  try `| filter: {name: courses.lecturer}` instead.

Comment: See [MDN JavaScript Reference - Accessing Array Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Accessing_array_elements).

Comment: @Claies The filter is also irrelevant. He just wants to present a single lecturer, so there's no need to use `ng-repeat` in the first place.

Comment: @ Claies  that worked a treat. It is always the little things

Comment: Also see [MDN JavaScript Reference - Array find() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

Comment: @SeanMcGrath If you only need to show a single lecturer, you really ought to do the filtering server-side. It's a bit of a waste of network data to retrieve all of them, just to filter most of it away. :-)

Comment: @ Nikolaj Dam Larsen I have edited the code, as i put up the wrong code first time. I am actually returning all the lectures at once. the function which I originally posted  lecturerFac.getLecturerByName([name]). I was trying to return the data through the stateParams but i was having trouble passing 2 prams at once, hence the reason for my current approach. Thanks tho.

Comment: @  Nikolaj Dam Larsen I agree with you that I should be filtering the data client side. But as I said in my previous comment, I was having problems passing 2 state params. I have asked a question on it before, but it went unanswered [you can look at it here ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42736462/passing-2-stateparams-using-ui-sref) any help on it would be great.